# Angular - How to test method that calls a callback

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm using Angular 11 with typescript and I don't know how to test the paths in which the method raise an exception.

```
  myMethod() {
    this.myService.callBackend(id).subscribe(() => {
       // do something when success
    }, responseKo => {
      if (responseKo instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (responseKo.status === 400) {
          // do something when we have bad request
        } else {
          throw responseKo;
        }
      } else {
        throw responseKo;
      }
    });
  }
```

As testing framework I'm using jasmine and karma.

How can I test the path when an exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

observables were implemented with ability to handle asynchronisity in mind. so you will be required to make your test asynchronious with the help of `fakeAsync`. in `fakeAsync` tests `tick` function allows you to "flush" everything hapenning asynchroniously. in your case it is possible to take advantage of that, and expect `tick` to throw. like this:

```
 it('should throw', fakeAsync(() => {
    of(true).subscribe(() => {
        throw new Error('something thrown');
    });
    expect(tick).toThrow();
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are mocking your service with spy methods at some point of test setup. to make your test go though error way just return error observable from your method. use `throwError` observable creation fn

```
it('it should react to errors', () => {
  serviceMock.callBackend.and.returnValue(throwError(myErrorObject));
  myComponent.myMethod();
});
```